# Passing parameter from paginated report down to stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am creating a Power BI Paginated Report using the stored procedure below to pass parameter in the report.
There are two parameters passed and it is cascading from one parameter to another e.g Timeframe parameter as By Month, By Week, By Dates dropdown and it cascade down to Calendar Date parameter.

[image]

Calendar Date parameter has the dropdown below when By Month value is selected from Timeframe parameter.

[image]

When By Week value is selected from the Timeframe parameter, the Calendar Date dropdown will be
[image]

TY means current year and LY means previous year e.g LY01 means pervious year week 01 and TY01 is current year week 01.
I created the stored procedure below but it does work for Timeframe: By Month. How can I incorporate By Week in the Timeframe and Calendar Date for LY01, LY02.... and TY01, TY02.... in stored procedure where clause.

Please, how can make this work so that when passing calendar Date parameter in paginated report will pass down to the stored procedure.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Test] (
            @CalendarDate varchar(50)
        )
as
begin
   declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)

   SELECT
    i.[Item Nbr]
    ,i.[Brand Name]
    ,i.[Calendar Date] as  Calendar_date
    ,i.[Asda Week]
    , AVG([sell_price])as [Avg_Price]
    , SUM([sell_price]) as [Sell_Price]
    , SUM([wkly_sales])as [wkly_sales]
    , SUM([wkly_qty]) as [wkly_qty]
    FROM dbo.vw_item as i
    WHERE       
    DATENAME(MONTH,i.[Calendar Date]) = CASE
                                        WHEN    RIGHT(@CalendarDate,2) = 'TY' 
                                        THEN    SUBSTRING(@CalendarDate,1,Charindex(' ',@CalendarDate,1)-1)
                                        ELSE    SUBSTRING(@CalendarDate,1,Charindex(' ',@CalendarDate,1)-1)  END

         AND    YEAR(i.[Calendar Date])=  CASE WHEN RIGHT(@CalendarDate,2) = 'TY'  
                                          THEN Year(Getdate())
                                          ELSE Year(Getdate())-1  END
    GROUP BY
    i.[Item Nbr]
    ,i.[Brand Name]
    ,i.[Calendar Date] 
    ,i.[Asda Week]
end
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work*. That tells us nothing about what the problem is.

Comment: @Stu - I have edited the statement. How can I incorporate By Week in the Timeframe and Calendar Date parameter for LY01, LY02.... and TY01, TY02.... in stored procedure where clause.

Comment: This sounds like you just need to add another parameter to the Stored Procedure that holds the By Week or By Month value so you can reference in in the script?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the timeframe parameter to the stored procedure.

Your where condition will have embeded case statments

Case when timeframe = 'By Month' then

DATENAME(MONTH,i.[Calendar Date]) = CASE
WHEN    RIGHT(@CalendarDate,2) = 'TY'
THEN    SUBSTRING(@CalendarDate,1,Charindex(' ',@CalendarDate,1)-1)
ELSE    SUBSTRING(@CalendarDate,1,Charindex(' ',@CalendarDate,1)-1)  END ...

when timeframe = 'By Week' then
....